# Setting background-color in div is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I am in a bit of a problem here. I am trying to set the background color of `<div id='coupons'>` but when I do, nothing is happening! Please help me out on this. I left a majority of the css as I do not have any conflicting background-color tags.

```css
#coupons {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='coupons'>
  <a id="coupons" name='coupons'>
    <div style="float:left">
      <img id='myImg' src="https://preview.ibb.co/jBYUxv/coupon1.png" id="i1" height="300px" width="600px">
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">×
        </span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption">
        </div>
        <script>
          // Get the modal
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
          // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
          var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
          var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
          img.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
          }
          // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
          // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
          span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='pformat'>
      <p>COUPONS FOR YOU!
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a black background behind the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div inside #coupon is floating, wich means #coupons colappses... meaning it has no height thus no backgroudn. try this... #coupons:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; } to clear its floating children.

Comment: Hey, I encountered a similar problem again however when I applied this solution to this problem. It didn't work. Same css but html is this: <div id='footer'>
    <h5>©Krish International Inc.</h5>
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

It appears your .png isn't transparent. The image itself has a white background.

The id #coupons is used more than once, perhaps this is giving unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar said, I can see the black behind the image, so I'm assuming you are looking for a `jQuery` solution.

*[In addition, @Joe B. makes a valid point about the transparency of you're png]*

If you're trying to change the background color with `jQuery` you can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
$('#coupons').css(`background-color`, 'pink');
```

```css
#coupons {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coupons">I am a coupons</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't see the black behind the image. I am not sure why. I reckon it must have to do with my monitor size.

Comment: @K.Patel - FWIW, I tend to wrap elements that need to maintain a certain padding, and might change (or not change) with the viewframe, within a "container" div. Such as `<div class="coupon_container"><div id="coupons">"other stuff"<div/><div/>`.  Also, while your code will work using duplicate element ids, try not to use the same one twice (your `<a>` tag.) Classes are much more effective to applying generic styles to multiple elements and the jq logic isn't much more difficult to do individual selections.